# How to insert term_taxonomy_id in wp_term_relationships table

Tags: php, ajax, database, wordpress

I am using wordpress 3.5.1, along with premiumpress- classifieds theme.

By Default in this theme, while adding listing there category in dropdown which consists of parent,sub category, and sub of sub category by differentiate by -- for sub category and --- for sub of sub category in same dropdown.In Addition they getting values of $_POST['CatSel'] in an array

I want to differentiate that by using ajax and I did. In First dropdown parent and second drop down child of parent and third dropdown as sub of sub category.

Here I facing risk as only my parent category is adding in a wp_term_relationships table.

Before I customize, in wp_term_relationships table term_taxonomy_id of parent sub category and sub of sub category id is storing

But after my customization, in wp_term_relationships table term_taxonomy_id of parent alone storing not a sub category and sub of sub category.

I don't Know how to insert my sub category and sub of sub category in wp_term_relationships table

Answer (score -1):

By this coding:

As Catsel[55] is sub category and CatSel[56] is Sub of sub category.

$val){ echo ''; $a++; } } ?>   
     
     
        " />
        "      /> 

   
    " />
    " />